# When are the dependencies of a Firebase Function installed on the hosting server? On deploy?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

As per https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/handle-dependencies :

"If you are deploying through the Firebase CLI, the local node_modules folder is ignored, and you must specify your dependencies in package.json"

Thus, are the dependencies in the package.json installed on deploy in the hosting server?

Comment: Yes, otherwise the code wouldn't work. Pretty sure the deploy runs `npm install` on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud Functions will effectively `npm install` after deployment to get a hold of all the dependencies for your code, as specified in package.json.

Comment: This is the only way to make sure everything is up to date.

Comment: Then how can he install local dependencies (using lerna monorepo paradigm) ?